# Python avoid mypy fails when redefining a class from another class in mutual reference

Tags: python, type-hinting, forward-declaration

Consider a pair of classes which represent the same thing in Python and each implements a method that converts one to the other. As an example consider transforming from cartesian to polar coordinates and viceversa.

```
@dataclass
class CartesianCoordinates:
  x: float
  y: float
  
  def toPolarCoordinates(self) -> PolarCoordinates:
      radius = ...
      theta = ...
      result = PolarCoordinates(radius, theta)
      return result
  

@dataclass
class PolarCoordinates:
  radius: float
  theta: float

  def toCartesianCoordinates(self) -> CartesianCoordinates:
    x = ...
    y = ...
    result = CartesianCoordinates(x,y)
    return result
```

Since I am using `PolarCoordinates` before it is defined, I've tried forwarding (actually redefining) its declaration by inserting the following lines before the `CartesianCoordinates` definition:

```
class PolarCoordinates:
    # forwarding declaration
    pass
```

This works, in the sense that the code runs correctly but checks like mypy will fail due to the class redefinition with an error like `Name PolarCoordinates already defined`.

I know a real forward-declaration in Python is not possible, but is there anything equivalent that allows to reference a class before it is completely defined and that allow s the python checks like mypy to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python supports forward type declarations.  You can either use strings:

```py
    def toPolarCoordinates(self) -> 'PolarCoordinates':
```

or import FROM THE FUTURE (no DeLorean required):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

…

    def toPolarCoordinates(self) -> PolarCoordinates:
```